# Litecoin privacy techniques

Tags: litecoin, privacy

What are the privacy techniques that used with Litecoin? and what are the differences between Bitcoin and Litecoin in privacy techniques?

Comment: As far as I know, Bitcoin and Litecoin implement transactions in exactly the same way, so the principles of privacy should be exactly the same for both.

Comment: + Litecoin is hardly used, so there's a much smaller pool of people to hide in (or mix with). Although I guess obscurity could be a plus in that no one is really interested in investigating it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no substantial technical difference between Litecoin and Bitcoin transactions.

Litecoin does not offer any additional "privacy techniques". The only differences are:

- address scheme: Litecoin addresses start with an L, Bitcoin standard addresses start wtih a 1.
- Volume: Bitcoin volume is much higher, so it might be easier to obscure a payment among the other transactions.
- Attention: Bitcoin might have more attention of law enforcement.

Note: The last two points are based on speculation.